# Error on Geting image from storage path in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to view image from storage path. My image is in storage/app/public folder. How can I view that. My code doesn't show image. Thanks in advance

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app/public/image_2018-02-17-21-32-05.png') }}" alt="..." style="">
```

Comment: I assume you have already linked the 'public/storage' to the 'storage/app/public' directory with "php artisan storage:link" ?

Comment: image directory is storage/app/public not public/storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command;

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then do this,

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/storage/image_2018-02-17-21-32-05.png') }}" alt="..." style="">
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration

Comment: image directory is storage/app/public not public/storage